# Change style overlay on android side-menu

Tags: javascript, react-native, styles, react-redux

When changing the style of the overlay in the "styles.js" (node_modules\react-native-side-menu\styles.js) file of "react-native-side-menu" this is not reflected, they do not change anything when activating the menu, if you can orientate I would be grateful.

I'm using this component: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu

Original:

```
overlay: {
...absoluteStretch,
backgroundColor: 'transparent'}
```

The change I'm making is:

```
overlay: {
...absoluteStretch,
backgroundColor: 'black',
opacity:0.6}
```

Comment: You are changing the library, try to rebuild your project and not just reload

Comment: gradlew clean and rebuild project not working overlay...